# Sum a number's digits until only one digit remain

Tags: code-request, number-theory

I want to iteratively calculate the sum of a number's digits, until the result contains only one digit. For example, when $n=67946$ we get:

$$6+7+9+4+6=32\space\to\space3+2=5\tag1$$

So, when $n=67946$ I must get $5$.

When $n=649134976$

$$6+4+9+1+3+4+9+7+6=49\space\to\space4+9=13\space\to\space1+3=4\tag2$$

So, when $n=649134976$ I must get $4$.

I wrote:

```
Total[IntegerDigits[n]]
```

But this only gives the first iteration of the sum of digits.

Comment: @infinitezero I stand corrected (and deleted the comment). Thanks! I think `Mod[n,9,1]` does the trick.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Clear[s, t, n]

t[n_] := NestWhileList[Total[IntegerDigits[#]] & , n, # > 10 &]
```

---

Test:

```
t[649134976]
```

> {649134976, 49, 13, 4}

If you don't want the interim values, use `NestWhile`.

---

A slight variation:

```
s[n_] := FixedPointList[Total[IntegerDigits[#]] & , n]
```

Test:

```
s[649134976]
```

> {649134976, 49, 13, 4, 4}

If you don't want the interim values, use `FixedPoint`.

Comment: Nice solution. I think the FixedPoint version is a bit neater